# Using kwargs in a function in Python properly

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

I am experimenting with the use of kwargs in a function in Python, but I can't get it right.

Here is what I attempted:

```
def f_add(x, y, a):

    return(x + y + a)

def f_add_wrapper(f_, b, **kwargs):

    return(f_add(x,y,a**b))

f_add_wrapper(f_ = f_add, b = 2, **{'x' : 2, 'y' :3, 'a' : 2})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-236-b37777c914bd> in <module>()
----> 1 f_add_wrapper(f_ = f_add, b = 2, kwargs = [2, 3,  2])

<ipython-input-229-5e01b9db8974> in f_add_wrapper(f_, b, **kwargs)
      1 def f_add_wrapper(f_, b, **kwargs):
      2 
----> 3     return(f_add(x,y,a**b))

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

f_add_wrapper(f_ = f_add, b = 2, **{x : 2, y :3, a : 2})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-b862f2191e7b> in <module>()
----> 1 f_add_wrapper(f_ = f_add, b = 2, **{x : 2, y :3, a : 2})

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: This error is not about `kwargs`, it is about `x` not being defined (it clearly isn't)

Comment: Are you trying to implement a decorator?

Comment: The use of `kwargs` is to be dynamic. You can't count on there being an `x` in the dict. Look at it through the eyes of the function: it does not know what x is, and can't count on the user to pass in `kwargs`

Comment: Inside wrapper function, `kwargs` is a dictionary.  Print it to be sure.

Comment: to understand better how this works, I would suggest calling the function **without** the wrapper, passing the dict like you did there. Will help you understand whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question right the solution would may be the following:
You have to change the `f_add_wrapper` method and pass the kwargs to the inner method.

```
def f_add_wrapper(f_, b, **kwargs):
    return f_add(**kwargs)
```

But i haven't used the args `f_` and `b` right now.
If you want to use  `f_` as method you have to write:

```
def f_add_wrapper(f_, b, **kwargs):
    return f_(**kwargs)
```

If you want to use the variable `a` as well, I would add a explicit to your list of arguments:

```
def f_add_wrapper(f_, b, a, **kwargs):
    a_to_power_of_b = a**b
    return f_(a=a_to_power_of_b , **kwargs)
```

With this solution every variable which is not explicitly mentioned in the list of arguments of the wrapper is passed to the inner function. The explicitly listed variables are accessible within the wrapper.